# cypress contains() returns the first member without using first/last

Tags: cypress-intercept

cypress
Replacing contains() with a command that automatically returns the first member without using first()/last() command

`cy.get('[data-cy="todo"]').children('[data-test="ttt"]').contains(id).get('[data-test="removebtn"]').click();`

It returns a list of elements - therefore it is not possible to click on an object list and only if I add first/last will the button click work

Comment: Are you trying to ask "how do I click on a specific element that matches the contains?"   If you know the index you can do something like `.contains(id).eq(index)`

Comment: you can also try to put contains back into your locator, like cy.get('[data-cy="todo"]').children('[data-test="ttt"]:contains("'+id+'")')